# python смена типа переменных с string на date

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Питон определил переменные с датами как "string", как преобразовать в нужный тип для сравнения?

Даты в переменных:

today - 2019,01,16

server - 2018,11,11

```
import subprocess
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
server = subprocess.check_output("команда_подключения", shell=True).decode('utf-8').strip()
today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y,%m,%d")

startDay = (today-server)
print(startDay.days)
```

Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    startDay = (today-server)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, весь стек с ошибкой в вопросе. А так, я понимаю ошибка в `today-server`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    startDay = (today-server)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Попробуйте заменить строку `startDay = (today-server)`  на  `startDay = datetime.strptime(today, "%Y,%m,%d") - datetime.strptime(server, "%Y,%m,%d")`

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает! startDay = datetime.strptime(today, "%Y,%m,%d") - datetime.strptime(server, "%Y,%m,%d")

Comment: Для сравнения даты можно никуда не преобразовывать: если дата идет в порядке год-месяц-день, то можно прямо в строковом виде сравнивать `'2019,01,16' > '2018,11,11'`

Answer (score 2):

Просто работайте с типами-датами, т.е. приведите `server` к типу даты:

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

server = subprocess.check_output("команда_подключения", shell=True).decode('utf-8').strip()
server = datetime.strptime(server, "%Y,%m,%d")
today = datetime.today()

startDay = today - server
print(startDay.days)  # 66
```

Comment: переменную server преобразовал, но возникла проблема, почему today в string?
today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y,%m,%d")

print(type(today))

<class 'str'>

Comment: Потому что ``strftime`` преобразует дату в строку.